# How do java interact with browser while doing automation (selenium) testing?

Tags: java, selenium, browser

I was asked a question in an interview - " How do java interact with browser while doing automation (selenium) testing?"

I replied - " Using Webdriver, the java inject the code in the browser which run the test as per code".

The interviewer was not impressed.

Could someone give the valid answer?

Comment: This probably isn't what he was expecting to hear either, but a key point of object-oriented languages like Java is that you don't care about how the third-party code you use does what it does; as a tester using Selenium, it would be a waste of your time to look into these implementation details.

Comment: @jsheeran As a software engineer using Selenium to testing multiple applications, it has **definitely not** been a waste of my time to look into the implementation details. In fact, it has allowed me to work around *many* Selenium bugs that have remained unresolved in Selenium for months or years, or to optimize my test suite so that it does not take forever to run. (Using Selenium naively will result in tests that can easily take twice the time they should.)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium RC works by injecting JavaScript into the launched instance of the Web browser and then the commands are passed to the browser based on which the browser behaves, in case of Selenium RC a Selenium RC server needs to be launched first which injects the javascript into the browser and acts as middleman between the Automation code and the browser

where as the Selenium WebDriver interacts with the browser using browser's native support for Automation.

References :-
1. [Guru99.com - Selenium WebDriver and Selenium RC comparision](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#how-does-webdriver-drive-the-browser-compared-to-selenium-rc)
2. [Selenium Documentation on Selenium Website](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-webdriver-comparison-selenium-rc.html)